# Get the deepest comment of every parent comment in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, comments

I have an array in React like this.

```
{  
"comments":[  
{  
  "id":1,
  "comment_text":"asdasdadasdsadsadadsa",
  "author":"adsfasdasdsad",
  "post_id":1,
  "children":[]
},
{  
  "id":2,      
  "comment_text":"idlsfg",
  "author":"asdsdasdad",
  "post_id":1,
  "children":[  
    {  
      "id":3,
      "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsfsdfsfsdf",
      "author":"sdfdsfdsfdsfds",
      "post_id":1,
      "children":[  
        {  
          "id":4,
          "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsdsfdsfds",
          "author":"sdfsdfdsfsdfdsfds",
          "post_id":1,
          "children":[  
            {  
              "id":5,
              "comment_text":"sdfdsfdsfdsfdssdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds",
              "author":"sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf",
              "post_id":1,
              "children":[]
            },
            {  
              "id":7,
              "comment_text":"sdfdsfdsfdsfdssdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds",
              "author":"sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf",
              "post_id":1,
              "children":[]
            }
           ]
          },
          {
          "id":6,
          "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsdsfdsfds",
          "author":"sdfsdfdsfsdfdsfds",
          "post_id":1,
          "children":[]
          }
        ]
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

Now, the result array will be the ids of the deepest comment in that parent comment thread. The result should be only of the deepest comments

```
[[1], [5,7]]
```

Now, I used recursion to get the depth of the comment but how get this array?

Comment: How the first one becomes null instead of `1`,  it should be [1,5] isn't it ?

Comment: Add your recursion code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122651/count-the-number-of-threads-on-a-parent-comment-in-reactjs

Comment: Theoritcally, this cannot work. A comment can have more than one child, and each of those children will have multiple children. You cannot find a singular, deepest comment. You can only get ALL of the individual deepest comment of every chain. There is a way to get the deepest, by counting how many levels deep you have gone into children, but even still you can have multiple comments with the same depth. I would recommend trying out another data structure.

Comment: The question is edited and the result should be the ids of all the deepest comment.

Answer (score 1):

We can use recursion here

```
var obj ={  
"comments":[  
{  
  "id":1,
  "comment_text":"asdasdadasdsadsadadsa",
  "author":"adsfasdasdsad",
  "post_id":1,
  "children":[]
},
{  
  "id":2,      
  "comment_text":"idlsfg",
  "author":"asdsdasdad",
  "post_id":1,
  "children":[  
    {  
      "id":3,
      "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsfsdfsfsdf",
      "author":"sdfdsfdsfdsfds",
      "post_id":1,
      "children":[  
        {  
          "id":4,
          "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsdsfdsfds",
          "author":"sdfsdfdsfsdfdsfds",
          "post_id":1,
          "children":[  
            {  
              "id":5,
              "comment_text":"sdfdsfdsfdsfdssdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds",
              "author":"sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf",
              "post_id":1,
              "children":[]
            },
            {  
              "id":7,
              "comment_text":"sdfdsfdsfdsfdssdfsdfdsfdsfdsfds",
              "author":"sdfsdfdsfdsfdsf",
              "post_id":1,
              "children":[]
            }
           ]
          },
          {
          "id":6,
          "comment_text":"fdsfdsfdsdsfdsfds",
          "author":"sdfsdfdsfsdfdsfds",
          "post_id":1,
          "children":[]
          }
        ]
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
 }

function getId(obj){
  const {id, children }  = obj
  if(children && children.length){
    return children.map(getId)
  }
  return id;
}
function getArrayDepth(value) {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? 
    1 + Math.max(...value.map(getArrayDepth)) :
    0;
}

var output = obj.comments.map(getId).map(k => {
  if(Array.isArray(k)){
    var d= getArrayDepth(k)
    return k.flat(d-2).find(a => Array.isArray(a))
  }
 return [k]
})
console.log(otput)
```

Comment: There is a small problem. Look at the question I have edited the array.